# Disable browser markup in contenteditable

Tags: html, browser, contenteditable

I want to disable browsers from adding anything other than HTML tags in my `contenteditable` div.

**Unequivocally, no ifs, ands, buts or candied nuts.**

Right now, Chrome in particular is really [irritating] me.

If I have a style set, say

`p { font-size:1.2em; line-height:1.6em; }`

It will say "oh, you must mean you want:"

`<span style="font-size:1.2em; line-height:1.6em;">stuff</span>`

I most certainly do not. In fact, I don't want it creating *ANY* span tags - ever. If I do, I will explicitly say so in my javascript, and not a moment before.

This is a highly frustrating problem, and I know `contenteditable` is still one of those *use at your own peril* web features chocked full of bugs and near-sighted "oh we should do..." by the browser developers that really just **suck** for making nice clean HTML.

**Is there anything I can do here?** I've already tamed "paste from Word" to fix MIcrosofts bastardized code soup, conquered most of `execCommand`s shortcomings, but this one.. this one.

I'll be [flustered] if I cannot work around the browsers injection of unwanted and unnecessary markup after coming this far, but I'm concerned. *Is there any hope?*

Comment: You'd have to parse the sanitize the content yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Webkit/Blink's world! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941 https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791 bugs reported nearly a year ago, upvoted many times and nothing.

Comment: I've seen the report, just left a comment. Very unfortunate. Very unpredictable. I was really hoping for an option to disable and have it text only. It sort of ruins the inline editing, but I suppose I'll just force users to edit items inside of a `textarea` until (and if) they do something to fix this.

Comment: @kcdwayne If you go with the route of forcing the users to use a textarea, you should remember that this is a bug specific to webkit, so you shouldn't penalize the rest of the browsers due to this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that can be applied to a `contenteditable` element, and it will ensure that the element ends with only a single child node of `nodeName` "#text".

```
var sanitizeContentEditable(elem) {
    var textContent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = elem.childNodes[i];
        textContent.push(child.textContent);
        if (child.nodeName !== '#text') textContent.push('\n');
    }
    elem.innerHTML = textContent.join('');
};
```

This function simply takes the text content of every child element, appends a newline to the contents of non-text child elements, and joins all such strings together, thereby ensuring that the `contenteditable` element has only a single, text-type child.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning "I don't want it creating ANY span tags - ever", what about using an Advanced Content Filter configured so that it does not allow span tags at all? That might work. Or configuring it to not allow `font-size` and `line-height` styles for spans, if you secretly do want spans to appear sometimes.